# Dirty Image Quality Assesment Measure

Tags: signal-analysis, noise, image-processing, measurement

I was looking for a way to measure how dirty is the document in image processing. Example images below:

a. Dirty Backgrounds

[image]

b. Dirty Backgrounds with Text

[image]

Can someone give me an initial idea to start my analysis?

Comment: Background only, or full document? The question sounds difficult. What do you want to use it for?

Comment: @LaurentDuval The background and the full document. I just want to assess how dirty the document is.

Comment: This will require you to spend some time thinking about what exactly you associate with the colloquial term "dirty". It can mean a lot of things. For instance, I guess we're not talking about dust or dirt but maybe more about stains and spills. But what does that mean, what is a stain? Patch of different color? What sizes are relevant, what relative color change? General inhomogenity of the background? That could be measured. What else? Cracks/Folds? I suggest you make a list of possible "contaminants" and their severity and how they would materialize in the image.

Comment: Indeed, the "just" seems to imply a form of simplicity. If there is not baseline method available, it's a good sign that it could be complicated, without more details, assumptions, modelling etc.

Comment: @Florian -> Is it ok to measure the amount of non-white pixels, then based from that give the document image quality score?

Comment: @Cubilla: That sounds like a question you would need to ask to yourself. ;-) We cannot no if that's "okay". It depends on what you want to do with it. Otherwise, from the images, it seems you have no white pixels at all.